# How to get rid of decimal overflow in python...I am trying to calculate the possible combinations a rubik's cube can have for an academic project

Tags: python, math, python-decimal

hey so I am trying to calculate the amount of possible combinations of a 2000x2000 rubik's cube,
and i written this code in python to calculate it, as online calculators i use and physical calculators all yielded no results. Do i need a beefier computer? or is this just simply unachievable?

the actual equation is 10^(((3.26017)*((2.00214)^(2000)))-6.51938), by normal calculator notation. If any of you can calculate it for me, please send me like a copy paste thing of the code if possible, thanks.

```
     import decimal
>>> decimal.getcontext().prec = 10000
>>> decimal.Decimal(10)**((decimal.Decimal(3.26017))*((decimal.Decimal(2.00214))**(decimal.Decimal(2000))))-(decimal.Decimal(6.51938))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    decimal.Decimal(10)**((decimal.Decimal(3.26017))*((decimal.Decimal(2.00214))**(decimal.Decimal(2000))))-(decimal.Decimal(6.51938))
decimal.Overflow: [<class 'decimal.Overflow'>]
```

Comment: You should always do a rough estimate first. The result has more the 2\*\*2000 digits, a number that is greater than the number of atoms in the universe. You need to rethink how to express this value. Working in logs (base 10) would be do-able.

Comment: Where did you get the formula from? I doubt that it's correct: the true number must be bounded by `(6 * 2000 * 2000)! / (2000*2000)!^6` (the number of possible permutations of the surface colours), which is a number that's _much_ smaller than the one you give.

Comment: (The actual number has somewhere around 15.5 million digits, so it should be reasonably easy to compute with appropriate big number libraries.)

Answer (score 0):

2.00214<sup>2000</sup> is a number of over 600 digits.  Multiplying it by about 3 and subtracting about 6 won't change that much.

The problem is that you then want to raise 10 to this power.  10 to the power of this number isn't a number with 600 digits, it's a number where the number of digits has 600 digits.  To store this number in memory you would require of the order of 10<sup>600</sup> bits.  An exabyte (assuming you could get a computer with this much memory)  is only about 10<sup>19</sup> bits.

In short, your number is *way* too large to be calculated.